# An alternative to responsive photos in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm currently creating a responsive website in Wordpress. I use large graphics of the features of my product that include text. Although the image resizes as the the width: 100% and height: auto, the writing becomes too small to read. I need a way to either show an alternative image or somehow code the image statically into the section. Any advise would be much appreciated

It's `<img src="http://wmgdev003.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/optik-top1.png" alt="" title="">`

css: width: 100% and height: auto

Comment: What code have you tried? Seems like something for media queries, but I don't know what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

could you replace your images with an elseif statement? 
here is how i do something like this

```
<?php if(!$detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() ): ?>
                                your desktop content goes here  
                            <?php else: ?>
                                mobile content goes here 
                            <?php endif; ?>
```

and that isMobile detect is based on http://mobiledetect.net/

You could call your large image and then call a smaller image?

Not sure if this applies because the question is a bit vague. it might help to give us examples.

Answer (score 0):

İf you have the original ones, by original i mean images without letters on it, you can make a css trick with textarea class.

1-Create a textarea at wherever you want to show your pics,

2-Give it a class

3-define background image as your product image.

4- write your letters inside textarea tags.